# How do i create a proper financial banking dashboard

Tags: dashboard, onlinebanking

hello please I really need help on creating a nice banking dashboard for a school project and I had installed a them to the website already but web theme has no dashboard and I have to create a better on and I don't know how to go on about that because am still a beginner

Comment: It's a project and am alone in This and that is why am here

Comment: You can see examples of admin templates, Sample school templates and get ideas from them. And most importantly, you need to know the needs of that school.